# Pentaho DI - Combine two column in one

Tags: pentaho, latitude-longitude

Hello I have two columns, longitude and latitude, I need to combine them into one geometry column like (longitude, latitude). I am new to pentaho, so please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Concat fields step under transformation category to achieve your result.

[image]